# What is the antonym of "feasible" for this context?

Tags: antonyms

> A. Business is feasible and may be accepted if the BC ratio is greater
>   than 1.
>
> B. Business is **unfeasible** and may be rejected if the BC ratio is
>   less than 1.

Can I use *non-feasible* instead of *unfeasible*?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the word *not* to negate the adjective:

> It is not feasible.

Or

> It is impossible under the circumstances.

That is the "natural" way to say it.  You might find some jargon-riddled contexts where *non-feasible* is used.

Comment: There's also "[impracticable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impracticable)" and "[infeasible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infeasible)". "Impossible" seems too strong a word to me.

Comment: **Impossible** isn't impossible. People use it far more often than they do "infeasible" to mean "cannot proceed given the requirements or circumstances".

Comment: **infeasible** is well-attested but appears mostly in technical contexts. It does not enjoy broad use among native speakers. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22infeasible%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: I didn't mean it as a criticism - a lot of folks use impossible where I wouldn't. I worked closely with my Japanese counterparts in a previous job, and saying something was "impossible" was frowned upon - it was just very, very difficult :) As far as infeasible goes, the context looked technical to me.

Comment: I didn't take it as a negative criticism but as a valid one -- I've added "under the circumstances" to the example in my answer  :)   A blunt and unqualified "impossible" is, as you say, not the same as "not feasible".